# Python requests module works on my Windows laptop but not on AWS

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am newbie about python so if i missed something basics i am sorry.
I have a code about getting information from a website and script works at vscode on my laptop but when i try same code with same loadings it doesnt work on AWS ubuntu and windows virtual computer. Here is the code:

```
url_arama = "https://www.sahibinden.com/otomobil/benzin,benzin-lpg/manuel/sahibinden?a4_max=250000&sorting=date_desc&a8=62068&viewType=Classic&a5_min=2004&price_min=25000&price_max=55000"
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url_arama, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")    

response = page.json()
print(response)
```

and the is output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SahibindenBot\aaa.py", line 26, in <module>
    sahibinden()
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SahibindenBot\aaa.py", line 24, in sahibinden
    response = page.json()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
```

i tried to reach google it works but thie website doesnt work why is that?

Comment: I doubt that code works on the other machine.

Comment: I'm guessing it has little to do with the environment. Take a look at the traceback and see what the error says.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'

Try this:

```
import json

response = json.loads(page)
```